# Practical Usage of N-Tier Architecture

Tags: n-tier-architecture

I'm a .NET web developer for a small organization. We have some skilled developers here, but what we don't have is anyone who's worked for larger, more organized, software shops.  We do all right, but I find myself wanting to structure my code better with little place to turn for advice.

It comes to this. At some point someone in our organization decided we were going to use webservices whenever we had to do any data access at all no matter the case. Thus, our hardware architecture is organized so that is the only way we can access our databases.  This sounds fine in theory, but the problem is most of our apps turn out like this:

Spaghetti Mess Of Code In The aspx.cs  ->  Web Service That Does Nothing But Call a Stored Procedure

Beyond that there's not much separation.  Whenever I start trying to research better structural practices I wind up reading about things like dependency injections, dirty properties, and class factories, my head starts to swim, and I move on to something else in frustration.

Here's a basic example of my wonderings. So let's say I have to make a page to select employees from a list, edit them, and update the database. Is it better to have the web service return an Employee object on a get, and accept an Employee object on an update? Or is it better to have the Employee object call the webservice to self populate?

In other words: Employee emp = svc.GetEmployee(42);  vs  Employee emp = new Employee(42);

The second example seems like it would be better organization for updates (update the relevant properties and call emp.Update()), but the problem is what if I need to get a list of Employees? It would be inconsistent to do Employee emp = new Employee(id); for a singular employee, but do svc.GetAllEmployees() for a list.

I feel like I'm rambling a bit so I'm going to cease trying to explain and hope someone understands my confusion. I appreciate any advice that anyone can offer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with anything, there are a number of different approaches you can take.  (So hopefully there will be a number of good and different answers here, because this is definitely an important question.)

One question you should probably ask yourself about your design is "how much logic will need to be shared between applications?"  Going with the small `GetEmployee` example you gave, it sounds like you want to know where to put the models in your domain.  Are these models used by multiple applications?  Is business logic shared across applications?

If so then you may want your domain models behind the web service.  Maybe build up a rich domain behind those services with its data access and external dependencies (remember that dependency injection thing, the best design decisions will need to be in the domain behind the service layer since that's the core of the whole system).

Then, of course, how do you access this logic?  Again, there are a lot of options.  My personal favorite design is to have a kind of request/response system that abstracts the service layer.  Something as cool as [NServiceBus](http://www.nservicebus.com/) for a really disconnected asynchronous system, something as simple as [Agatha](http://code.google.com/p/agatha-rrsl/) for just abstracting out the actual service and putting the request/response logic in code, or maybe play around with [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) (something I've been meaning to do) or another project, etc.  Hell, you could just roll a plain old WCF or even SOAP service layer and nothing more.  It's up to you.

At that point you're looking at a fairly procedural system at the service layer.  This isn't a terrible thing.  Think of the service layer like an MVC site.  You send it a request, populated with some kind of incoming viewmodel, it does its domain stuff in all its object-oriented goodness, and returns a view in the form of some XML representation of an outgoing viewmodel.  Now you have a repeating pattern.  Your client-side applications are just great big views for your domain.  The dumber they are, the more interchangeable and replaceable they are, the better.

This allows you to encapsulate various "business actions" in a [unit of work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) at the service boundary.  Given a request from a client application, either the whole thing succeeds or the whole thing fails.  Wrap it up in good error handling and an application-level error/exception logger to give you all the details of the failed requests.  (Imagine that every request can be serialized to a string and included in an error message.  Now you have everything you need to recreate the error in a simple string, as opposed to asking users "what did you click on?" to try to recreate errors.)

If, instead, the back-end doesn't really share anything with different applications and each application is its own distinct entity entirely.  At that point you don't really need to share all that logic behind the service layer, and it's entirely possible that you *shouldn't* try to make any kind of overlap.  Is the data access the only thing that's behind the service?  What about things like filesystem access or external web service access?

If the only thing behind the service is the data access, then you can keep your models and data access repositories in your client applications like you seem to be accustomed to and just swap out your repository implementations with implementations that internally reference and access the service layer.  (This would be the second option in your `GetEmployee` example.)  Properly abstracted, direct access vs. service access repositories can be swapped out trivially depending on where the application needs to live.

Of course, this leans a little towards a true persistence-ignorance approach, which can be dangerous.  Performance implications need to be considered.  Some piece of logic or unit of work on the back-end may hit the database several times to do several things.  If this is happening across a service then that adds service overhead to each database call.  So you'll want to address this on a case-by-case basis.

I guess I may be rambling at this point, so to get back to something concrete it really comes down asking yourself some questions about your domain.  How persistence-ignorant can you afford to be?  Do your applications share business domain logic?  Do you need to access other non-database external dependencies behind the service only?  There's no universal design that's always the right answer.  You'll probably end up experimenting with various designs and homogenizing on a design that's right for your developers and your environment.

Comment: Thanks for your very thorough answer! In a lot of cases we do small side projects that don't have a lot of business overlap. Most of our cross application code (Active Directory access, exchange server access) are in web services and while we don't use a service bus of any kind we at least share info that way. Thanks again.